# IE posts a dynamically creted form without parameters

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, forms, post

So i am generating form on fly and posting it to another website. The problem is that when i'am using IE form post request contains no parameters. The form outerHTML is the same in Mozilla and IE 8, so i just can not understand it does not work properly in IE 8.
Is there any way to fix ?

Here is the logic that posts generates & posts the form:

```
function PostForm() {
    var form = AddForm();

    var email = hiddenEmailCtrl.value;
    var password = hiddenPasswordCtrl.value;
    var checked = rememberMeCtrl.checked;

    AddField(form, "email", email);
    AddField(form, "password", password);
    AddField(form, "remember_me", checked);

    form.action = 'https://somesite.com/login';

    alert(form.outerHTML);
    alert(document.forms[1].outerHTML);

    document.forms[1].submit();
}

function AddForm() {
    var submitForm = document.createElement("form");

    document.body.appendChild(submitForm);

    submitForm.id = 'credentialsForm';
    submitForm.method = "post";
    submitForm.target = '_blank';

    return submitForm;
}

function AddField(formElement, fieldName, fieldValue) {
    var inputElement = null;

    if (typeof (document.all) != undefined && document.all) {
        inputElement = document.createElement("<input type='hidden' name='" + fieldName + "' value='" + fieldValue + "' />");
        inputElement.id = fieldName;
    }
    else {
        inputElement = document.createElement('input');

        inputElement.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
        inputElement.setAttribute('name', fieldName);
        inputElement.setAttribute('value', fieldValue);

        inputElement.id = fieldName;
    }

    if (inputElement == null) return null;

    formElement.appendChild(inputElement);
    return inputElement;
}
```

And here is Mozilla request :

```
POST /login HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: ensiconnect.groupsite.com
Content-Length: 42
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

email=some@email.com&password=somePassword
```

This is IE8 request:

```
CONNECT somesite.com:443 HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.1; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; AskTbF-ET/5.9.1.14019)
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 0
Host: ensiconnect.groupsite.com
Pragma: no-cache
```

Comment: This feels very familiar to me and for some reason, I want to say that IE doesn't like it when you dynamically change the form action and will do weird, inconsistent things when you do so. Can you demo it without updating the form action? Also, can you explain why you're doing exactly whatever it is that you're doing?

Comment: Not really. I have an aspx page that is doing postback with it own form, but at some conditions it should post this form to a different website. I've tried to made static form, fill it with js and post it, but causes problems with postback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE uses a nonstandard version of `document.createElement` that also supports HTML code instead of a simple tag name. Since this violates the standard, and IE8 went to some length to be more compliant, it's possible IE8 only obeys the non-standard variant in quirks mode.

You should try removing the switch on `document.all` and pass IE8 the w3c variant in `AddField`. If that works then you'll need to test for IE7 rather than document.all

btw, I'm just guessing here, you'll need to test it.